# Does making a char* point to another string literal leak memory?

Tags: c, string, memory-leaks, c-strings, string-literals

I Have some misunderstanding regarding this simple example:

```
char *s = "abc";
s = "def";
```

Will the assignment of the second string cause a memory leak, or it will be replaced properly? If the former is true, how do I replace the value of `s` the right way?

Comment: It's not a memory leak in the traditional sense - it is not a bug. But you will have the literal "abc" sitting uselessly in your program, adding 4 bytes extra to the program size (oh no!). Most likely an optimizing compiler will get rid of it though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. There's no memory leak.

You have simply changed `s` to point to a different string literal which is fine (with this: `s = "def";`).

Put simply, if you haven't allocated anything yourself using `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc` or any function that returns a dynamically allocated memory (and documentation tells you to `free()`. For example, POSIX's [`getline()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getdelim.3.html) function does that), you don't need to `free()`.

Comment: I'm fairly certain `getline()` uses `realloc()` to resize a buffer if necessary, so you would need to use `free()`, especially if it fails.

Answer (score 6):

Both strings are defined statically so there's no memory leak. What would leak would be:

```
char *s = strdup("abc");  // dynamic memory allocation
s = "def";
```

Actually there's a small static memory waste (wouldn't call that a leak) since you're not able to use `"abc"` anymore.

But since it cannot be repeated even by calling the routine where your code is located, I definitely wouldn't call that a leak.

Now if you have `char s[] = "abc";` (array, not pointer), and a `"def"` string of equal size, you could do:

```
strcpy(s,"def");
```

to replace the contents of the string (but don't do that on a statically assigned pointer like defined your code: undefined behaviour).

Comment: "memory waste" Can't understand what is this, Is it dangerous?

Comment: No. You just don't have the use for "abc" memory. Not dangerous just useless

Comment: Your code is a memory leak - the space dynamically allocated by `strdup` was not freed

Answer (score 0):

Your code segment:

```
char *s = "abc";
s = "def";
```

will not cause a memory leak. `char *s` is a pointer in memory. When you use `char *s = "abc"`, you set a string literal that `*s` can point to. When you set `s` to the string literal `"def"`, all you are doing is changing where `*s` points to.

**Note:** You can only do this with **pointers**, and **not** arrays. If you want to use arrays instead, you may need to use [`strcpy(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html)/ [`strncpy(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy).

Since you haven't allocated any pointer, either with [`malloc(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc)/[`strdup(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup), it is difficult to get a memory leak.

However, here is an example of a memory leak:

```
const char *str1 = "abc";
const char *str2 = "def";

char *s1 = malloc(strlen(str1)+1); /* dynamic memory allocation with malloc() */
char *s2 = malloc(strlen(str2)+1);

s1 = s2;
```

Here you set `s1` to `s2`. Therefore, this means the memory location of `s1` does not exist anymore, as `s1` is pointing to `s2`, and not the original memory location it was allocated. You can no longer deal-locate this pointer using [`free(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/free), as their is no longer a reference to its location. If you never `free()` a pointer allocated on the heap, that will also cause a memory leak.